# Can the airport keep my luggage for a few days?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, connecting-flights, icn

I'm going to Asia for the summer. I'd like to take a flight going to Seoul/Incheon from San Francisco. I's like to stay there for a few days to tour around. Then I would fly to Manila. So my question is, would the airport keep my luggage for like 2 days. Us Filipinos take boxes to go visit the Philippines. I wouldn't like to take a few heavy boxes outside the airport in Korea.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to look at whether ICN has a luggage storage service.  If so, expect there to be a fee.

Answer (score 6):

Neither the airline nor the airport will store your luggage for you, but there is a left-luggage service at Seoul/Incheon available in both terminals.

You can book storage online at [www.trazy.com](https://www.trazy.com/experience/detail/seoul-luggage-storage) Prices vary by size and storage period, but a 'medium' item will cost you US$11.20 for two days. Note that each item you want to store is priced separately.

The company also has other sites in Seoul that might suit your itinerary better.

Disclaimer: This is just one possible service I identified on the web. I make no recommendations, and other services may be available.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://www.skyscanner.co.kr/news/services-which-you-enjoy-find-icn) indicates that there are a few companies providing luggage storage. CleanUpAir [what a name...] and SpaOnAir [I think, the Korean version is not that obvious] are on B1, near the train station entrance. Hanjin and CJ are on the check-in counter floor, near M and A respectively.